# Using VLOOKUP across Spreadsheets.

Tags: excel

I have two spreadsheets. I'm trying to use VLOOKUP, but it simply is not being nice. The cell that's suppose to be updated does not.

-Spreadsheet A has indices that need to be paired with Spreadsheet B indices.

-Then I need to get the corresponding value to that indices. Those values are one cell to the right of the indices in Spreadsheet B.

-The value in Spreadsheet B then needs to be placed in its appropriate cell back in Spreadsheet A.

If someone could help that would be great and ... fabulous. If you need more details or clarification let me know. I have a feeling it might be my using of Table Name across spreadsheets as the culprit for it not working properly.

Comment: please put the VLOOKUP formula your are trying that is not working.  It would be difficult to give you a specific answer on your vague description.

Comment: "Spreadsheet" is a little ambiguous. Do you mean different *worksheets* or different *workbooks*?

Comment: Both spreadsheets are on the same workbook.

Comment: @ScottCraner The formula I'm using is VLOOKUP('Cell', 'Created table name', 'column with return values', FALSE).

Comment: Since `'column with return values'` is not a valid name this isn't the formula that you are using. Why not give the actual formula that you are using?  In any event -- my guess is that you need to qualify some of the ingredients by the appropriate sheet reference e.g. have something like `Sheet2!'column with return values'`

Answer (score 0):

Try using and Index Match combo function

Index('Column/array with return value',MATCH('Value to match','Array to find the value',0-For an exact match),'column number of the Column/Array to look in')

I am not a fan of VLOOKUP as I almost always find errors with it. There are plenty of indexMatch examples too on here and Google.